# How to make item pairs from the same big list in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

For example: [0,1,2,3]
expected results [0,1], [0,2], [0,3], [1,2], [1,3], [2,3]

Comment: iter_tools permutations,combinations?

Comment: Clarify more plz.

Comment: No i need like I explained in problem body

Comment: @BassemSamir Read the docs for itertools, they're quite good IMO.

Answer (score 0):

Use combinations from itertools

```
 from itertools import combinations
 x = combinations(lst,2)
```

https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations